# Use AJAX and Controller to Populate Index page by Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, viewbag

I have an ASP.Net Core project and I used EntityFramework to scaffold using CRUD. I have my view pages and I want to make my index page dynamic. I have a hierarchical database where it is in this order, Department, SubDepartment, Machine, Equipment, Problem. I have already made queries for different views where I return data based off a dropdown selection. My question is how do I enter queried data into the table to display in Index?

There are many options and I am not sure where to start. Here are some of my thoughts.

1. Return the queried data to the view as a JSON and sort of manually parse it into the table.
2. I am not sure on this one but could I just add the queried data into a ViewBag or ViewData and it would automatically be added to the table?

As of now, I already have a JSON that is being returned into the view.

EDIT: I just remembered that ViewBag/ViewData is likely not an option because to my understanding those require a page refresh. So my question now is how can I parse a JSON into a EntitityFramework created table?

Comment: try both, see which one works

Comment: @Bravo Do you know how to go about doing my option 1? I don't really know how to do it. If you see my edit I believe option 2 is ruled out.